# Java: Optimization of checking Attribute of ObjectList andObject2List

Tags: java, optimization

Hi just wanna ask you guys if there is a way to optimize this: Perhaps library methods can help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < obj.size(); j++){
        if (ids.get(i).equals(obj.get(j).getChatId())){
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `List<Object> obj`?

Comment: You could use more appropriate data structures for your abstraction and, for example, filter "obj" by passing a predicate to reject objects with `id` that `ids` doesn't contain. No library is going to help you if you're too lazy to properly design your model.

Comment: What do you want to do with the objects that match your condition? To collect to another list?

Comment: obj is just a List<ownCreatedObj> which contains the ids as well as other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs in *O(n*m)* time, because of your nested loops.

To improve that, first convert your `ids` collection into a `Set`.

```
Set<IdType> idSet = new HashSet<>(ids);
for (ObjType o : obj) {
    if (idSet.contains(o.getChatId())) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since `add()` is *O(1)*, the set construction is *O(n)*, and since `contains()` is also *O(1)*, that means the performance of the new code is *O(n+m)*.